# FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion formatting

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, fileversioninfo

Is there a specific culture setting that governs how the `ProductVersion` string is delimited and that can be set through the `CultureInfo` class?

For example, using the following line on a Windows 10 PC, with the region set to English (South Africa), the `ProductVersion` string is returned as 1,2,3,4 instead of 1.2.3.4.

```
string version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("myApp.exe").ProductVersion;
```

From my testing thus far, none of the `NumberFormat` decimal separator options applies to the `ProductVersion`.

Comment: `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` is a wrapper around the Win32 `GetFileVersionInfo` function, and the `ProductVersion` is obtained through a call to `VerQueryValue`, which can offer the information in different code pages. The localization of this bypasses what .NET itself is doing. You could try getting a local-independent `Version` by using the separate fields (`new Version(v.ProductMajorPart, v.ProductMinorPart, v.ProductBuildPart, v.ProductPrivatePart)`); this is not guaranteed to match the arbitrary `ProductVersion` string exactly, though.

Comment: For example, `cmd.exe` reports a `ProductVersion` of `10.0.18362.1` on my machine, but the `ProductPrivatePart` is `449`. Even so, the version numbers are actually comparable, as opposed to the strings.

Comment: The native VERSIONINFO definition is quirky in many ways.  This is one of the quirks, it defines *two* sources of product version.  One is a string, returned as-is without any culture sensitive formatting.  The one you obtained with ProductVersion.  So you got what the original programmer used as a string.  The other is an actual number, returned by the ProductMajor/Minor/Build/PrivatePart properties.  They don't have to agree.  Clearly you prefer the latter properties to get it formatted the way you want.